# Use NFS on ubuntu that has 2 NICs. Client cannot mount the directory

Tags: nfs, nic

I have been suffering from this issue for a while now. I have a computer (Say, A) running ubuntu and has 2 NIcs. One NIC is connected to the home network and the other is connected to the isolated private network. There is another computer (B) in the private network created by A. They are both linux. A has a NFS folder and I would like to mount it on B but it doesn't let me and the server complains that the permission denied. The firewalls are both turned off and I edited fstab and exports. Interestingly when B is on the home network B can mount the NFS directory with no problem. This behaviour concludes that the problem seems to reside on the NFS server settings. Because the NFS server has 2 NICs it seems to like to use the NIC that is connected to the home network rather than the private network. How can I switch from the home network to the private network ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question? It is very clear and to the point

Answer (score 0):

what is in your /etc/exports file? You should allow mount from private network ant mount with the name ( or IP ) of the private interface of A. Let say your computer a has two IP addresses

home: 192.168.1.1/24
  private: 10.0.0.1/24

and B has
  10.0.0.2/24

Then /etc/exports should looks like:

/home 10.0.0.2(rw,...)

and on B you should mount as:

mount 10.0.0.1:/home /mnt